# Makeing my first discord bot while learning python.... Bot wont post the picture i want it to

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Ok so im still learing and discord is the first API I decided to work with. So far after a few teaks and adjustments ive gotten a good bit to work. Then I thought a welcome message would be great to make. So heres the code and the error:

```
@client.event
async def on_member_join(members):
    channel = client.get_channel(919804032011341824)
    with open('my_image.png') as f:
        picture = discord.File(f)
    await channel.send('Welcome user! Its not safe to go alone. Here take this!', picture)
```

Error that shows:

```
Ignoring exception in on_member_join
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Python Projects\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ccarr\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\Discord Bot\main.py", line 33, in on_member_join
    await channel.send('Welcome user! Its not safe to go alone. Here take this!', picture)
TypeError: send() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the file in binary mode. `discord.File` takes a [binary input](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/master/api.html#discord.File.fp).

In order to send files, you need to specify [`file` or `files`](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/master/api.html#discord.TextChannel.send) as an argument in the function.

```
with open("image.png", "rb") as f:
    picture = discord.File(f)

await channel.send("...", file=picture)
```

Comment: you are a dicord.py god

Comment: @ChrisCarroll Everything is on the docs. Take a look at them :)